# Error building Xamarin iOS project

Tags: msbuild, xamarin.ios, xamarin

After switching to the unified API, while I try to build an iOS application using Xamarin.iOS, I'm getting an error:

**error : Error building target _DetectSigningIdentity: Unknown char**

Anyone has an idea how to solve it or understands what causes this error?

This is the detailed trace:

> error : Error building target _DetectSigningIdentity: Unknown char
>   Error building target _DetectSigningIdentity: System.FormatException: Unknown char
>   at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Single.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionFactorExpression.NumberEvaluate (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionRelationalExpression.BoolEvaluate (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionAndExpression.BoolEvaluate (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ConditionParser.ParseAndEvaluate (System.String condition, Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project context) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskBatchingImpl.Execute (IBuildTask buildTask, TaskExecutionMode taskExecutionMode) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskBatchingImpl.Build (IBuildTask buildTask, TaskExecutionMode taskExecutionMode, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetBatchingImpl.RunTargetWithBucket (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 bucket, Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetBatchingImpl.Run (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetBatchingImpl.Build (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target target, System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Target.DoBuild (System.Boolean& executeOnErrors) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: What is your locale? What OS are you building this on?

Comment: If you edit your Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets file and edit the Condition expression for the _DetectSigningIdentity target by changing `'$(IsAppExtension)'` to `'$(IsAppExtension)' == 'true'`, does that fix it?

Comment: I've changed it to 
<Target Name="_DetectSigningIdentity" DependsOnTargets="_DetectAppManifest" Condition="'$(OutputType)' == 'Exe' Or '$(IsAppExtension)' == 'true'">
But it still throws this error.

Comment: I'm buliding it on Mac OS X 10.9.5.
i need to mention it's happening after I converted a project to the unified API, I can build other projects that aren't converted.

Comment: What is the value of your TargetFrameworkVersion in your .csproj file?

Comment: <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: Can you paste your .csproj file to gist.github.com or pastebin?

Comment: Yes, here it is:

http://pastebin.com/9Y0R4UDA

Comment: Just noticed you also asked about the locale, here are the details:
Region: Israel - Hebrew
Preferred languages: English - Primary

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your .csproj. Something is trying to parse a float and the text given to it is not valid (perhaps because your locale is non-English?), but I have no idea what it is trying to parse.

Comment: I have tried changing the locale to US, but still I get the same error.

I do realize it's trying to parse something and did try searching where ConditionFactorExpression.NumberEvaluate is using Double.Parse, but with no luck.

Comment: That method is in MSBuild or XBuild depending on whether you are building on Windows or Mac (respectively). ConditionFactorEvaluate.NumberEvaluate is not in the targets file or in your code.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have tried to look for the source on the web to better understand what happens under the hood, as I really don't know what else can i do.

Comment: Look for Single.Parse() or float.Parse() which internally calls Double.Parse().

Comment: What else can be done to try and fix this? should i open a bug on bugzilla? it's the third day I'm on it now.

Comment: I was able to build the project after changing the locale (although I've tried it before), clean-all and restart to Xamarin studio.